# How to Run a SQL Query on Multiple Tables

Tags: sql

I am building a database which contains components for vehicles. There are three tables:

- Vehicle Table (List of vehicles where every vehicle has a unique ID number)
- Tires Table (Lists the serial number (SN) and part number (PN) for tires along with the vehicle that it's installed on (ID))
- Filter Table (Lists the serial number (SN) and part number (PN) for filters along with the vehicle that it's installed on (ID))

I would like to create an Access SQL query which pulls the serial numbers and part numbers for all of the filters and tires installed on a certain vehicle (Let's assume that we're searching for a Honda Civic which has a vehicle ID of 5). I created the following code but it returns the cartesian product of all of the results. There are two filters and two tires installed on each vehicle so it returns the following results where the results are combined and duplicated.

- Tire 1 (PN and SN) | Filter 1 (PN and SN)
- Tire 1 (PN and SN) | Filter 2 (PN and SN)
- Tire 2 (PN and SN) | Filter 1 (PN and SN)
- Tire 2 (PN and SN) | Filter 2 (PN and SN)

Is there anyway that I can create a query which returns:

- Tire 1 (PN and SN)
- Tire 2 (PN and SN)
- Filter 1 (PN and SN)
- Filter 2 (PN and SN)

My code is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tires.SN, Tires.PN, Tires.ID, Filters.ID, Filters.PN, Filters.SN,
Vehicle.ID 
FROM (Vehicle 
INNER JOIN Filters ON Vehicle.[ID] = Filters.[ID]) 
INNER JOIN Tires ON Vehicle.[ID] = Tires.[ID] 
WHERE Vehicle.[ID] = 5;
```

Comment: Your data isn't quite normalized since tires and filgers have the same data in them (at least with your example, it might be best to just have one table and define if the component is a "tire" or a "Filter" this way you don't have to select from both.  Additionally if you decide to add "belts" later, you don't have to write more queries, the data will drive out additional components.

Comment: To answer your question though it can be done using current schema, however we have to make the assumption that there are always 2 tires and 2 filters per vehicle and that the lower ID of filter is tied to the lower ID of tire for the same vehicle.  If you're going to scale the databse over time, this will get harder and harder to maintain.

Comment: Why do you need them as columns? It's not scalable as xQbert said. Just select them as rows combining result sets.

Comment: Further to this, if you put all of the components into one table, you will not have this cartesian product issue. You just need to consider whether you need to store component specific attributes such as filter type (paper etc.) vs Type type (radial, etc.). If so it get's a bit tricky, but there are various models to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need it just for a single value of Vehicle.ID then you can use a query with `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT 'Tire',Tires.SN, Tires.PN 
FROM Tires
WHERE Vehicle.[ID]=5
UNION 
SELECT 'Filter',Filters.PN, Filters.SN
FROM Filters
WHERE Vehicle.[ID]=5
ORDER BY 1;
```